# Am I ever required to sell a stock?

Tags: penny-stocks

I bought some shares of a distressed company that I thought had a good chance of a turn around. Unfortunately, it did not, and the stock now trades OTC for less than 2 cents.

My shares are worth about $15, but the commission I'd have to pay for a sale is $25, so I would incur a further loss of $10 just to sell.

Will I ever be compelled to close out this position?
Can I just let it sit fallow forever and never pay this commission?

Comment: My broker has a form to relinquish worthless securities.  You have the power to choose the tax loss harvesting year.

Comment: There are situations where you have to sell.  For instance, a former employer was taken over, and I received cash for the stock I held (without any option for e.g. stock in the new company).  But there were no brokerage fees or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I just let it sit fallow forever and never pay this commission?

Generally yes. There is no one forcing you to sell anything.

The other things to consider is;

- Some brokers allow worthless stocks to be relinquished.
- If the company does not shut down properly; you may be holding something that you can't sell or do anything.
- Some brokers charge a small fees to carry the shares ... check if this is the case.